# Alternate Color Of Paragraphs

Tags: html, css

I want to changes the color of paragraphs to attracts the customers. My code is below

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>hhjl</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p style="color: blue;"><b>Hello</b></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

The current color of paragraphs is blue but I want to change it to red/green etc for attraction. I am not here use blink instead trying to use change the color of words. How to do?.

Comment: It seems to me that you would benefit a lot from doing some reading up on HTML and CSS, and perhaps doing some online learning/tutorials. StackOverflow is really for asking questions that go beyond basic questions like "how can I change the colour of a paragraph?". Try http://www.htmldog.com/guides/

Comment: Why? Whether a question is "basic" or not is completely relative and an arbitary figure. Stack overflow is a place to ask questiosn and get answers, although present its a place to ask a question and have people criticise it in the hopes the get a virtual pat on the head in the form of an upvote.

Comment: Please specify what you mean by “change it to red/green etc”. Do you mean it should automatically change from one color to another? Immediately or slowly? Or that the color should start from one color and change to another in some direction (i.e. a gradient)? The question is too vague to be answered in its present form.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela, it should change the color slowly. you are get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an animation to change the color:

```
p{
    color:blue;    
      -webkit-animation: color 1s linear 0s infinite alternate;
     -moz-animation: color 1s linear 0s infinite alternate;
          animation: color 1s linear 0s infinite alternate;
}

@-webkit-keyframes color { from { color:blue; } to { color:red; }  }
   @-moz-keyframes color { from { color:blue; } to { color:red; }  }
        @keyframes color { from { color:blue; } to { color:red; }  }
```

Take a look at the **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6ytAk/1/)**.

Ressources:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/@keyframes
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/animation

Comment: How do i utilize it in html?.

Comment: hm, i think you really have to take a look at the basics of html and css. This is css, you embed this into the html via a `<style>` tag in the head or in a separate `*.css` file and reference it: http://www.cssbasics.com/

Answer (score 1):

```
<p style="color: red;"><b>Hello</b></p>

<p style="color: green;"><b>Hello</b></p>
```

Change the color on each paragraph according to which color you want to use. You also have a wealth of color codes to choose from http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_colors.asp

Comment: I don't want to create separate paragraphs. I just want to imply it only on one paragraphs.

Comment: OK in that case use the same code but within the DIV tags at the top X

Comment: w3schools is a [bad source](http://w3fools.com/). Refer to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/) or [sitepoint](http://www.sitepoint.com/) for quality information instead.

Comment: @Christoph Wow I knew nothing about that. Thank you these other two seem good

Answer (score 0):

Put the paragraph between div and after that set the color of that div with css. Another simpler option is to use something like that `<p style="color:cyan;">` or you can specify the color using RGB.